# Using local variables in global scope after exiting function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

i understand that AS3 works in the following way

```
var str1:String = "Global"; 
function scopeTest () 
{ 
    var str1:String = "Local"; 
    trace(str1); // Local 
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(str1); // Global
```

how can i make it work like this? see the last line

```
var str1:String = "Global"; 
function scopeTest () 
{ 
    var str1:String = "Local"; 
    trace(str1); // Local 
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(str1); // Local
```

Comment: There are tons of online sources when you write 'variable scope'. You could have read at least a little before asking question that is so fundamental and was answered so many times..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str1:String = "Global"; 
function scopeTest () 
{ 
    //use the global variable here
    str1 = "Local"; 
    trace(str1); // Local 
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(str1); // Local
```

OR use this

```
var str1:String = "Global"; 
function scopeTest () 
{ 
    //use "this" keyword
    this.str1 = "Local"; 

    var str1:String = "Local";
    trace(str1); // Local 
} 
scopeTest(); 
trace(str1); // Local
```

Full sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                scopeTest(); 
                trace(str1); // Local
            }

            public var str1:String = "Global"; 
            public function scopeTest():void 
            { 
                //use "this" keyword
                this.str1 = "Local"; 

                var str1:String = "Local";
                trace(str1); // Local 
            } 


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: the one with this does not work. the first one works

Comment: Check the full code. It works. You can omit the public and return type as in your original post, the compiler will shout but it will still work.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `var` keyword in a new scope, it attached a new property to that scope. Simply omit the *declaration* of `str1` within the function:

```
function scopeText():void
{
    str1 = 'Local';
}
```

This will look to the outer scope for an existing property `str1`.

Comment: @user3699728 If that's the case then your example code might not match what you actually have.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name to avoid conflict.  Var names are cheap. Why reuse them, especially if it is even remotely possible that they could cause a conflict?

Comment: i was just understanding the scope of vars in as3